# error calling nested stored procedures mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I m calling a stored procedure inside another stored procedure in **MySQL**

The error i m getting on calling simply using Mysql administrator

```
call sp_update_back_image(2, 3);
```

is: -

```
OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine void.sp_sel_options_id is not a variable 
or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

The stored procedures...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_update_back_image`(uid int , img_id int)
BEGIN
call sp_sel_options_id(uid, oid);
select oid;
END
```

The sp_sel_options_id is: -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_sel_options_id`(IN uid int, 
OUT r_id int)
BEGIN
    set r_id = 0;
END
```

Any Help

Thanks

Pradyut

India

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup

the other variable needs to initialized or ordered in the calling variables...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_update_back_image`(uid int , img_id int)
BEGIN
declare oid int;
call sp_sel_options_id(uid, oid);
select oid;
END
```